# PrimeFaces DataTable with scrollable header

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, scroll

I have a PrimeFaces dataTable and I want to make its header scrollable. I am going to embed an image into header so when the content is scrolled down, image should disappear. Code looks like;

```
 <p:dataTable id="dataTable" liveScroll="true"
                     value="#{....}" var="...." scrollable="true"
                     scrollRows="3"
                     scrollHeight="490" rows="3">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/..."></p:graphicImage>
            </f:facet>
            <p:column ........
```

Comment: you want the header scrollable (?) is this link solve your problem  http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableScrolling.jsf

Comment: no. primefaces showcase has datatables which has fixed headers.

Answer (score 0):

you can put it into a scrollPanel

```
<p:scrollPanel>
     <p:dataTable id="dataTable" liveScroll="true"
                 value="#{....}" var="...." scrollable="true"
                 scrollRows="3"
                 scrollHeight="490" rows="3">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:graphicImage value="/images/..."></p:graphicImage>
        </f:facet>
        ...
</p:scrollPanel>
```